# Get element ID on click and send them to form

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

A client needs a system in which their customers will be able to check the photos (displayed on a grid) and send an e-mail (via a form placed below the photo grid) with the photos' IDs.

The first alternative that came in mind was apply the onclick to get the photos' ID, but I have no idea how to send them to the form.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily, just run the onclick event to get the id which you store in variable and then replace the form input tag value with this value:

```
var id; // contains image id

$("input").val(id);
```

or if you have more input tags then add id attribute to them and change corespondingly the selector. And then you can fire the submit button to post the form data.

Or more advanced yet in this case more appropriate way is to send data with ajax without the need of any form.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on replying, Matúš. Unfortunately the client gave up the idea. Thank you anyway for the answer.